# Resource Files for Delphi

Tags: delphi, resources

everytime i write a resource file (.rc) and drop it over the bcc32.exe, nothin happens. if i drop it over rc.exe, it gives me a .res file, which doesnt work in delphi.

so what do i have to write in the .rc file, to get my .res built correctly at the bcc32?
(example pls)
lets say i wanna have abc.wav, which is on my desktop.
thanks

Answer (score 11):

It's brcc32.exe that you want, not bcc32.exe.

That should produce your .res file for you.

However, you could also look into changing your {$R} directive slightly so that you don't need to manually compile your .rc file.

IIRC, you can use `{$R yourfile.res yourfile.rc}` in your source, and Delphi should compile the .rc for you.

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. I'll delete it.

Comment: and the rc file is

abc.wav c:\user\desktop\abc.wav
so i just save this as a .rc and put it in my project's folder?

the sourcecode, how does it have to be then? both,rc and res {$R lala.res lala. rc}
or just the .rc ?

by the way, thanks for your good answer, i didnt know that i can use .rc directly in delphi oO

alex

Comment: Francois has already clarified some of this, but maybe this answer will help also:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298031/including-resource-file-in-a-project-by-rc-file-rather-than-res-file

Answer (score 10):

If you have D2007 or newer, just add your RC file to the project manager...

The RC file is a simple text file where you declare your resources and the corresponding files (with path if needed) like:

```
SANTA  BITMAP "SANTA.BMP"
SOUND  RCDATA "SOUND.WAV"
```

In D2009 or newer, you can just add the wav to the project manager.
And the easiest way to "add" is to drag your file and drop it there.

Comment: with this "add to project" window, i
normally use for adding a new unit?

Comment: ah sry for doublepost, but i dont know how to write the .rc file yet. just  name c:\...\....\abc.wav     ?

ill go to bed now, ty for your help, ill try it tomorrow

Comment: @alex, the .rc file is just a text file, containing 3 space delimited fields.  The first is the internal name, the second is the type (RCDATA is a catch all type) and the third is the filename of the resource to compile.

Comment: so:
abc RCDATA "abc.wav"
if the .rc is in the same folder like the wav?