# How to Put Icones in RadStudio XE8 IDE palette for new component?

Tags: delphi, components, palette, delphi-xe8

I wrote a set of few components named :
 - TUser
 - TRESTAccess
 - TServerAccess

Then i create 3 PNG image 100x100 with same name than component (in the same directory than the BPL and the .PAS files)

I wrote a  .RC file include in my package.

But can't compile : invalid format ?

does someone have any ideas how can i make the icones appear 
in the component palette ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way to make a component icon in Delphi XE using only the built in tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999939/best-way-to-make-a-component-icon-in-delphi-xe-using-only-the-built-in-tools)

Comment: brcc32 doesn't support png. MS res compiler rc does. Use that to compile the resource script.

Comment: Thank you for your help. No need extra compiler or ressource editor.. it work well with the standard editor. Just need BMP proper files and using standard ressource editor.

Comment: Do it your way then. But you'll have to live with the large size of those uncompressed images.

Comment: oh !! you are right.. 65,7Kb.. following your comment i change the size... now its only 4.2 kb. THank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to compile BRCC32

- I used image 128x128 BMP format.
- I click on Project / Ressource and Image
- I added the image and rename identifier as the name of my component
- Then uninstall package (then closed Rad Studio XE8, if not i get and access violation)
- Then install my package again.

IT WORKS !  (except transparency : in the palette no transparency applied, but if i drop the component in my form, the transparency is applied !)

[image]