# Delphi 10 Seattle - [dcc32 Error] E2161 Error: RLINK32: Unsupported 16bit resource in file "C:\Development\Testing\Unit1.dfm"

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have an issue with the compile of  a long running project which is now showing the error indicated above. The issue arises from a specific component which is in herrited from TCombobox. If I place the component in on a blank form with no other controls the project will compile and run. I then save the project and re-open then re-compile the project will give the error. The only solution is to remove the component and put it back in which then allows the project to  compile and run until it is closed and re-opened again.

I am currently upgrading from XE4 to 10 Seattle and have two identical copies of the full project code and the error is occuring in both.

Any ideas would be most appreciated

Comment: How can we reproduce this?

Comment: If only we knew what this inherited component was...

Comment: Its a version of the standard combo with some additional features which allow additional properites to be stored and for it to deal with security. The problem is why should a stable component suddenly start to give issues in this way and in such a curious maner, I was hoping someone would have seen the behaivour of the IDE particularly why the re-opening of the project should trigger the issue.

Comment: Why don't you make a [mcve]?

Comment: We have no idea what "additional properties" this custom control has, nor who the vendor is. Is it from a third-party library? Did you write it? Did your friend write it for you? Does it make use at all of any resource files? What types of custom properties does it have? What version of Delphi was it designed for?

Comment: By "suddenly" do you mean it's happened since you upgraded to Seattle?  It wouldn't be the first time a new IDE has unmasked a problem with an apparently well-behaved component.

Comment: Why do we have to guess. Isolate the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: This type of error message should have a well-defined meaning. If the OP needs to simplify a whole big project down to few files to isolate the origin, this might take days of work. Consequently, I understand if the question comes without an MRE. We have to be practical. BTW, my comment is a bit late, sorry for this.

Comment: Could be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298031/including-resource-file-in-a-project-by-rc-file-rather-than-res-file

Answer (score 0):

When this occurred in a Delphi 10.2.3 app, I noted that a similar app had System.UIConsts above several FMX entries in the Uses clause, so I moved it up in this app and the problem went away.