# PNG image from imagelist

Tags: windows, delphi, png, delphi-2010, delphi-xe6

How do I take a picture from a `TImageList` and put it into a `TImage` (or return it as a `TGraphic`)?

The important point is that a `TImageList` can contain 32-bpp alpha blended images. The goal is to get one of these alpha-blended images and place it in a `TImage`. This means at some point i would likely require a `TGraphic`. Although, strictly speaking, my question is about placing an image from an **ImageList** into an **Image**. If that can be accomplished without an intermedate `TGraphic` then that is also fine.

## What do we want?

We want the guts of a function:

```
procedure GetImageListImageIntoImage(SourceImageList: TCustomImageList; 
      ImageIndex: Integer; TargetImage: TImage);
begin
   //TODO: Figure this out.
   //Neither SourceImageList.GetIcon nor SourceImageList.GetBitmap preserve the alpha channel
end;
```

There can also be another useful intermediate helper function:

```
function ImageListGetGraphic(ImageList: TCustomImageList; ImageIndex: Integer): TGraphic;
var
//  ico: TIcon;
    bmp: TBitmap;
begin
    {Doesn't work; loses alpha channel. 
    Windows Icon format can support 32bpp alpha bitmaps. But it just doesn't work here
    ico := TIcon.Create;
    ImageList.GetIcon(ImageIndex, ico, dsTransparent, itImage);
    Result := ico;
    }

    {Doesn't work; loses alpha channel.
    Windows does support 32bpp alpha bitmaps. But it just doesn't work here
    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Imagelist.GetBitmap(ImageIndex, bmp);
    Result := bmp;
    }
end;
```

Letting us convert the original procedure to:

```
procedure GetImageListImageIntoImage(SourceImageList: TCustomImageList; ImageIndex: Integer; TargetImage: TImage);
var
   g: TGraphic;
begin
   g := ImageListGetGraphic(SourceImageList, ImageIndex);
   TargetImage.Picture.Graphic := g; //Assignment of TGraphic does a copy
   g.Free;
end;
```

I also some random things:

```
Image1.Picture := TPicture(ImageList1.Components[0]);
```

but that does not compile.

P.S. I have Delphi 2010

Comment: "I get a runtime error" means nothing unless you tell us what error, including the exact error message and any memory addresses.

Comment: @Ken - I bet it's a compile time error since there's no 'Pictures' property for a TImage, and even if it was 'Picture' that code wouldn't compile (picture <> component).

Comment: @Sertac, I agree. It would help, though, if the question contained the info. People seem to forget that we can't see their screens from where we sit. (At least I can't, and psychic debugging should be a last resort. <g>)

Answer (score 2):

```
ImageList1.GetBitmap(0, Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
```

Comment: @Giacomo - What's the problem, transparency is lost?

Comment: `TImageList` only supports ICO and BMP formats. Putting a PNG into a `TImageList` converts it to a BMP. If you want to preserve a PNG as a PNG, you have to use another component that supports that, such as a `TPngImageList`.

Comment: Add your PNG to a resource... then load it from the resource... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153394/how-do-i-make-a-png-resource

Comment: @GiacomoKingPatermo for 32 bits png images, you can use the `GetIcon` method to extract the image and preserve the transparency , so try   `ImageList1.GetIcon(0, Image1.Picture.Icon);`

Comment: @Giacomo - Nobody knows the problem until you tell it. How does "it doesn't work"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Error: List index out of bounds (0)

Comment: @Giacomo - It looks like it is raised from somewhere else in your code. You're probably using a list, listbox etc.. and have an error with it.

Comment: @GiacomoKingPatermo how many images are contained inside ImageList1?

Comment: @GiacomoKingPatermo can you add your .png image to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Routine to get a transparent graphic out of an **ImageList**:

```
function ImageListGetGraphic(ImageList: TCustomImageList; ImageIndex: Integer): TGraphic;
var
    ico: HICON;
//  png: TPngImage;
//  icon: TIcon;
//  bmp: TBitmap;
    wicbmp: IWICBitmap;
    wi: TWicImage;
begin
{   //Works. Uses our own better Wic library.
    ico := ImageList_GetIcon(ImageList.Handle, ImageIndex, ILD_NORMAL);
    Result := TWicGraphic.FromHICON(ico);
    DestroyIcon(ico);}

    //Works, uses the built-in Delphi TWicImage (careful of VCL bugs)
    ico := ImageList_GetIcon(ImageList.Handle, ImageIndex, ILD_NORMAL);
    wi := TWICImage.Create; //Due to a bug in the VCL, you must construct the TWicImage before trying to access the Wic ImagingFactory
    OleCheck(TWicImage.ImagingFactory.CreateBitmapFromHICON(ico, wicbmp));
    wi.Handle := wicbmp;
    Result := wi;

{   //Doesn't work, loses alpha channel
    icon := TIcon.Create;
    ImageList.GetIcon(ImageIndex, icon, dsTransparent, itImage);
    Result := icon;
    }

{   //Doesn't work, loses alpha channel
    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    bmp.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Imagelist.GetBitmap(ImageIndex, bmp);
    Result := bmp;
    }

{   //Fails: cannot assign a TIcon to a TPngImage
    icon := TIcon.Create;
    ImageList.GetIcon(ImageIndex, icon, ImgList.dsNormal, itImage);
    png := TPngImage.Create;
    png.Assign(icon);
    Result := png;
    icon.Free;
    }

{   //Working failure; doesn't support stretched drawing (e.g. TImage.Stretch = true)
    icon := TIcon.Create;
    ImageList.GetIcon(ImageIndex, icon, ImgList.dsNormal, itImage);
    Result := ico;
    }

end;
```

Sample usage:

```
g: TGraphic;

g := ImageListGetGraphic(ImageList1, 7);
Image1.Picture.Graphic := g;
g.Free;
```

> **Note**: Any code released into public domain. No attribution required.