# brcc32 invalid bitmap format (loosing image quality)

Tags: image, delphi, components, icons, delphi-2010

I created a delphi component and want to load an image into it at runtime.
So i created a .RC file in notepad.

```
useIdentifer BITMAP "demo.BMP"
```

When i compiled the file it gave me an error "invalid bitmap format", so I did some research and got the solution that  I had to check that the file is 8-bit, so I converted it to bitmap 256 colors using paint, but due to this i lost the quality and pixels of image.

I'm not sure how can i get rid of the error without losing quality of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Use a PNG image instead of a BMP. The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153394/how-do-i-make-a-png-resource) will tell you how.

Comment: A BMP will work, just use the RCDATA resource type, or a 3rd party RC compiler that supports bitmaps with higher bit depths